# CodeIgniter Fetching Records From More Than Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-2

I'm developing an application, Where in I've defined following tables.

```
storytags
id  cover_title                   user_id
1  love happens two times?         1
2  revolution 2020                 2
3  wings of fire                   3
4  night at the call centre        4

storytag_invitations
id  storytag_id  user_id
1      1            1
2      2            2
3      3            3
4      4            4
users
id  name
1  suhas
2  sangu
3  praveen
4  sangamesh
```

I want to fetch the storytags where storytag_invitations.user_id != storytags.user_id and storytag_invitations.storytag_id != storytags.id for the user 3

I've tried the following query

```
select storytags.cover_title
from storytag_invitations
join storytags
on storytags.id != storytag_invitations.storytag_id and storytags.user_id !=  storytag_invitations.user_id
where storytag_invitations.user_id = 3
```

But I'm getting duplicate rows. Please suggest some solutions. Its been two days I'm trying this. The work will be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql works for me when I use from:

```
select s.cover_title
  from storytag_invitations si, storytags s
 where s.id != si.storytag_id
   and s.user_id != si.user_id
   and si.user_id = 3
```

You can check it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecd77/4

Answer (score 1):

Try if it works for you:

```
$sql    = "select storytags.cover_title from storytags, storytag_invitations where ( storytags.id != storytag_invitations.storytag_id and storytags.user_id !=  storytag_invitations.user_id ) and storytag_invitations.user_id = 3";
$rs     = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you are using codeigniter then try this
$this->db->select("table1.column1,table1.column2,table2.column");
$this->db->join("table2","table1.column = table2.column");
$resultset=$this->db->get();
```